# How to count total comment?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, count

I've the following tables:

```
   fss_post(post_id,text)
   fss_comment(idComment, post_id, text)
```

Is possible to write a query that give me as result a row for each post_id with total comment count for this post?

EXAMPLE:

```
    post_id       comment_count
    101010        5
    101011        0
```

And so on...
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. Google `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This question can be answered with [minimal research effort](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
p.post_id,count(*) 'comment_count'
from
fss_post p
left join fss_comment c on p.post_id = c.post_id
group by p.post_id
```

Comment: it was nothing, anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Select post_id, COUNT(comment_id) from comments GROUP BY post_id;